# Twitter Timeline Feed (HTML5/CSS3)

Tags: html, css

I need to add a twitter feed to a web project for college. I've never done this before so forgive me for my ignorance. I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work (and the twitter instructions aren't very clear). We have not yet learned JavaScript so I am trying to achieve this using only HTML/CSS. Please check my code & give me a solution. Thanks.I have tried both examples below:

In example 1 the iframe is displaying with nothing inside it.
In example 2 only a link to the page is being displayed.

```html
<div id="container-4" class="container">
  <h3>Twitter</h3>
  <iframe class="twitter-timeline"
          href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev"
          data-tweet-limit="3">
    Tweets by @TwitterDev
  </iframe>
</div>
```

```html
<div id="container-4" class="container">
  <h3>Twitter</h3>
  <a class="twitter-timeline"
          href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev"
          data-tweet-limit="3">
    Tweets by @TwitterDev
  </a>
</div>
```

Edit: Sorry for all the edits, this is my first question on here. :L
I took the following steps to get an embeded code:
- Visited https://publish.twitter.com/#
- Entered https://twitter.com/extremeironing in the search box.
- I then selected embedded timeline.
- Copied and pasted the following code (which did not work):

```html
<a class="twitter-timeline" 
   href="https://twitter.com/extremeironing">
   Tweets by extremeironing
</a> 
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

- After this attempt I moved onto trying the first 2 examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: How do I display a Twitter Timeline Feed on a webpage using only HTML and CSS?

Comment: thats way too broad.

Comment: Should i use an iframe?

Comment: you should look in twitters documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already looked at it. I also used the embed code provided by https://publish.twitter.com/# and it does not work. I'm just wondering if i'm missing something.

Comment: *I also used the embed code provided by publish.twitter.com/# and it does not work.* Can you be more specific with the steps you took on that page and update your question with the code it produced?

Comment: The code created by that page does not match what you have in your question.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I should have been more clear on the steps I took. My bad.

Comment: The first snippet (iframe) doesn’t work but the others seem fine. http://jsbin.com/nagaqisoxi/edit?html,output You may have some other script error(s) on the page that are preventing the Twitter embeds from loading. If you have a Content Security Policy (CSP) enabled, you may need to whitelist `platform.twitter.com`.